# How to insert markup into fragment using Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to declare some layout to use as template for all form fields.

So given roughly this fragment

```html
<div th:fragment="control(input)" class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Edition description</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input th:replace="${input}">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this fragment "invocation"

```html
<div th:replace=":: control(~{:: input})">
    <!--Want to reference this one, not all inputs-->
    <input th:field="*{editionDescription}" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="перераб., дополн.">
</div>
```

It would produce the following result:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Edition description</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input th:field="*{editionDescription}" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="перераб., дополн.">
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that `:: input` input selector is applied to all `<input>` tags in currently processed template. How do I reference only enclosed one?

Additionally, can you give an advice on how to approach this in general. I want to mimic Grails Fields plugin as much as possible. Do you think I'd better declare my own dialect?

Comment: It looks like `~{:: input}` is a selector for all the "input" elements. Since you would like it to only apply to a specific element you need to identify which element with a selector - something like `~{:: input.my_input}` and then define the input field with `class="my_input form-control"` ...

Comment: Would this happen to be part of a public git repo that you could share with us? It would be easier to answer the question if I could play with your Thymeleaf a little.

Answer (score 0):

You should be defining **classes (or identifiers)** to your **input elements** *(the ones you want to replace)* and then you can use the appropriate selector syntax just to select the desired input. You can find selector syntax details in [here](https://www.attoparser.org/apidocs/attoparser/2.0.0.RELEASE/org/attoparser/select/package-summary.html)

Sample code might look like this:

```
<div th:fragment="control(input)" class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Edition description</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input th:replace="${input}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your selector should be like:

```
<div th:replace=":: control(~{:: input.description})">
    <!--Want to reference this one, not all inputs-->
    <input th:field="*{editionDescription}" type="text" class="form-control description"  placeholder="перераб., дополн.">
</div>
```

Please note the use of ***:: input.description*** as a selector with class identifier